# Coverity reports error when compiling cpp code with string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, coverity

I've compiled a simple program given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char s[30] = "Hey there!";
    string_view sv(s, 7);

    cout<<"s: "<<s<<endl;
    cout<<"sv: "<<sv<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using below command:

```
cov-build --dir idir --config /home/d3v/cov-analysis-linux64/config/coverity_config.xml g++ --std=c++17 dev.cpp -o dev
```

Results on to console:

```
Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 8.7.1 on Linux 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64
Internal version numbers: a59584cec3 p-lodi1-push-28091.44.570


[WARNING] Emitted 0 C/C++ compilation units (0%) successfully

0 C/C++ compilation units (0%) are ready for analysis
 For more details, please look at: 
    /home/d3v/d3v/idir/build-log.txt
```

tail of build-log.txt file:

```
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997198Z|cov-build|19858|info|> Build time (cov-build overall): 00:00:02.288773
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997198Z|cov-build|19858|info|> 
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997678Z|cov-build|19858|info|> Build time (C/C++ emits total): 00:00:00.903396
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997678Z|cov-build|19858|info|> 
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997678Z|cov-build|19858|info|> 
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997725Z|cov-build|19858|info|> [WARNING] Emitted 0 C/C++ compilation units (0%) successfully
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997725Z|cov-build|19858|info|> 
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997725Z|cov-build|19858|info|> 0 C/C++ compilation units (0%) are ready for analysis
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997725Z|cov-build|19858|info|>  For more details, please look at: 
2020-09-14T11:34:00.997725Z|cov-build|19858|info|>     /home/d3v/d3v/idir/build-log.txt
```

Error from buil-log.txt file:

```
[STATUS] Compiling dev.cpp
/home/d3v/cov-analysis-linux64/bin/cov-emit --dir=/home/d3v/d3v/idir --ignore_path=/tmp/cov-d3v/891bff16bbd88b7b80d27daaef3e5a81/cov-configure --ignore_path=/tmp/cov-d3v/891bff16bbd88b7b80d27daaef3e5a81/cov-d3v/2d94633aecadf2b164c84654240d09d0 --add_type_modifier=__coverity___fpreg --add_type_modifier=__coverity_decimal --no_predefined_feature_test_macros --no_stdarg_builtin --incompat_proto --no_predefined_cplusplus -w --no_predefines --comp_ver 8.3.1 --char_bit_size=8 --gnu_carriage_return_line_terminator --wchar_t_keyword --no_multiline_string --no_trigraphs --ignore_calling_convention --enable_80bit_float --enable_128bit_float --macro_stack_pragmas --exceptions --arg_dependent_overload --no_predefines --pre_preinclude /home/d3v/d3v/idir/emit/a7f5e15a0c55/config/988f58815e9372b14b5ed84fa4afe3d5/g++-config-0/coverity-macro-compat.h --pre_preinclude /home/d3v/d3v/idir/emit/a7f5e15a0c55/config/988f58815e9372b14b5ed84fa4afe3d5/g++-config-0/coverity-compiler-compat.h --preinclude /home/d3v/cov-analysis-linux64/config/template-g++-config-3/../user_nodefs.h --c++ --allow_incompat_throw --new_array_args --type_traits_helpers --c++14 --gnu_version 80301 --no_trigraphs --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8 --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/backward --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include --sys_include /usr/local/include --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include --sys_include /usr/include -D__NO_INLINE__ --type_sizes=e16Pdlx8fiw4s2 --type_alignments=e16Pdlx8fiw4s2 --size_t_type=m --ptrdiff_t_type=l dev.cpp
"/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../includ
          e/c++/8/type_traits", line 1049: error #255: type name is not allowed
        : public __bool_constant<__is_assignable(_Tp, _Up)>
                                                 ^

"/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../includ
          e/c++/8/type_traits", line 1049: error #255: type name is not allowed
        : public __bool_constant<__is_assignable(_Tp, _Up)>
                                                      ^

"/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../includ
          e/c++/8/type_traits", line 1049: error #20: identifier
          "__is_assignable" is undefined
        : public __bool_constant<__is_assignable(_Tp, _Up)>
                                 ^

"/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../includ
          e/c++/8/type_traits", line 2929: error #255: type name is not allowed
        remove_cv_t<remove_all_extents_t<_Tp>>
        ^

"/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../includ
          e/c++/8/type_traits", line 2928: error #20: identifier
          "__has_unique_object_representations" is undefined
      : bool_constant<__has_unique_object_representations(
                      ^

Emit for file '/home/d3v/d3v/dev.cpp' complete.
[ERROR] 5 errors detected in the compilation of "dev.cpp".
WARNING: cov-emit returned with code 1
```

Binary was generated, but I'm unable to understand why Coverity is reporting an error and `cov-emit` is returning 1. Please help me with this.

OS: CentOS 7
gcc version: 8.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of error indicates a problem in the Coverity tool.  The Coverity compiler, `cov-emit`, is failing to compile source code that the native compiler (in this case GCC) accepts.  Thus, it has some sort of unintended incompatibility.

In this case I think the main issue is the Coverity release is older than the compiler, and hence lacked support for it.  [GCC 8.3 was released in February 2019](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html), while [Coverity 8.7 was released in January 2017](https://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/13983/239595/whats-new-in-coverity-8-7).  For each new supported compiler release, the Coverity team may need to make adjustments specific to that compiler and its bundled header files.  The Coverity documentation lists exactly what compiler versions are supported.

So, that suggests two possible solutions:

1. Use a more recent Coverity release.
2. Use an older compiler, one that was out and officially supported when Coverity 8.7 was released.

Association disclaimer: I used to work for Coverity/Synopsys.

Comment: Thank you Scott, i would try out both of your suggestions